# How to get copy of birth certificate from Hildalgo, Mexico from 1927?

Tags: birth-records, 1920s, mexico

Is getting a copy of a birth certificate from Hildalgo, Mexico from 1926 or 1927 easy for a non-Spanish speaking amateur?  If so, how might I go about doing that?  If not, how might I go about finding a genealogist in Mexico to assist me in this and some other research of a person born in Mexico and her parents?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] for some quick tips on how the site operates.  I hope you will enjoy asking and answering questions here.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of a professional genealogist experienced in research in Mexico, this turned out to be a simple task.  There was a border crossing record for the person in question (who had an unusual first name) and for each of her sisters. The sisters' crossing records confirmed the identity of the person in question as did the date of birth.  The crossing record gave the city of birth.  The birth record itself was found on familysearch.org. The birth record was in a 2800 page hand-written document, covering 4 years, and it took some manual scanning, but with the date of birth and an unusual first name the search did not take long.